# Timing inconsistent for CAN message transmission

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, can-bus, c++-chrono

I am attempting to write a program in C++ that does some video processing using OpenCV and then uses the information from the video to send a message onto a CAN bus using PCAN-basic.
When the code for the CAN bus is running by itself, the timing on the messages are pretty good i.e. the system that I am talking to does not complain. However when the OpenCV part of the program is introduced, then the cycle time intermittently increases to an unacceptable value, which causes issues.

I am using chrono::high_resolution_clock to compare a start time and the time now. If this comparison is >10ms then I am sending a CAN message and restarting the clock.

I have tried the following:

Updated OpenCV to latest version (in hope that it would run faster/free up resources)

Set the thread priority of the thread that the CAN message function lives in, to be of a higher priority. Set as 0, which I assume is the highest priority.

Lowered the comparison to send out the message at 8ms, this was intended as a workaround, not a fix.

```
//Every 10ms send a CAN signal
chrono::duration<double, milli>xyTimeDifference = timeNow - xyTimer;
xyTimerCompare = xyTimeDifference.count();

if (xyTimerCompare > 10)
     {
        if (xyTimerCompare > 16)
        {
            cout << "xyTimerComapare went over by: " << xyTimerCompare << endl;
        }
        result = CAN_Write(PCAN_USBBUS1, &joystickXY);
        //Reset the timer
        xyTimer = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        if (result != PCAN_ERROR_OK)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Is there a better method to obtain a reliable signal to within +/- 1ms?

Comment: From what kind of system, a PC?

Comment: Yes it's a PC based solution. Using the PCAN-basic API to send a message onto the CAN bus via a PCAN-USB interface. I have four threads running within my code, but everything starts to get out of time when I introduce the thread that is running OpenCV.

Comment: Are you using any runtime for managing the threads? Like, e.g. threading building blocks? Or are you using bare-metal pthreads?

Comment: Schoolboy error - I was running my code in debug mode.